# invoke_long_callback in Taipy

Tags: callback, invoke, taipy

I need run a "long_callback fuction" for long time task.   I didn´t understand well  about the callback details(link:  https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/.)

I have the button:

```
<|INICIAR|button|on_action={on_iniciar_ini}|id=btn01|>
```

and the callbacks

```
def on_iniciar_ini(state, id, action):
    notify(state, "info", "Heavy task started...")
    invoke_long_callback(state, on_iniciar, [...heavy_function arguments...])

def on_iniciar(state, id, action):

    C4=state.Jiga.Status_AI0()  #with Pulldown 
    C3=state.Jiga.Status_AI1()  #with Pulldown 
    ...more code
```

When I use without "heavy_function arguments"

```
 invoke_long_callback(state, on_iniciar, [])
```

I had the error

TaipyGuiWarning: invoke_long_callback(): Exception raised in function on_iniciar().
on_iniciar() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'state', 'id', and 'action'

I dont understand if i need pass again the parameters in the "heavy_function arguments", this is, the state, ID or especify all state variables that I use inner the on_iniciar function, for example state.Jiga

[image]

When I use:

```
def on_iniciar_ini(state, id, action):
    notify(state, "info", "Heavy task started...")
    invoke_long_callback(state,on_iniciar(state))
    #invoke_long_callback(state, on_iniciar, [])


def on_iniciar(state):

    C4=state.Jiga.Status_AI0()   
    C3=state.Jiga.Status_AI1()  #with Pulldown
... more code
```

My code run, but I have an exception in thread

> Exception in thread Thread-64 (user_function_in_thread): Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\jaime.rodriguez\MULTELETRONIC\SoftJigas\PP000938_SoftJig.venv\lib\site-packages\taipy\gui\gui_actions.py",
> line 341, in user_function_in_thread
> res = user_function(*uf_args) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py",
> line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py",
> line 953,  in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\jaime.rodriguez\XXXX\XXXX\PP000938_SoftJig.venv\lib\site-packages\taipy\gui\gui_actions.py",
> line 344, in user_function_in_thread
> callback_on_status(False, e, user_function.**name**) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**name**'. Did you
> mean: '**ne**'?

Someone please help me to understand how make the long callback!

Comment: Hey Jaime, Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the `invoke_long_callback` is typically to handle long functions without blocking the GUI (asynchronous call). Two functions usually are passed to the `invoke_long_callback`.

1. The first is your heavy task, which will take a lot of time. This function cannot have the *state* as an argument. You can put all the parameters that you want before calling this function.
2. The second function is the function that is called with the *state*. The goal is that this function will be called at the end of the heavy task function. It can also be called at a specific frequency if wanted. The goal is to be able to actualize the web page after the execution of the heavy task.

In your example, `on_iniciar()` is your heavy function and should not have the state in its parameters. Its parameters should be whatever you want and be transferred in the heavy function through the `invoke_long_callback`:

```py
def on_iniciar_ini(state, id, action):
    notify(state, "info", "Heavy task started...")
    C4=state.Jiga.Status_AI0()  #with Pulldown 
    C3=state.Jiga.Status_AI1()  #with Pulldown
    ... 
    invoke_long_callback(state, on_iniciar, [C4, C3, ...], on_iniciar_finished)

def on_iniciar(C4, C3):
   # more code that does your heavy task
   ...

def on_iniciar_finished(state, status):
    # code that will be executed at the end of the task
    if status:
        notify(state, "success", f"The heavy task has finished!")
    else:
        notify(state, "error", f"The heavy task has failed somehow.")
```

You can get the result of your heavy function in `on_iniciar_finished` if needed.

Example of code using `invoke_long_callback`:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, Markdown, invoke_long_callback, notify
import numpy as np

status = 0
num_iterations = 10_000_000
pi_list = []

def pi_approx(num_iterations):
    k, s = 3.0, 1.0
    pi_list = []
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        s = s-((1/k) * (-1)**i)
        k += 2
        if (i+1)%(int(num_iterations/1_000)+1) == 0:
            pi_list += [np.abs(4*s-np.pi)]

    return pi_list

    
def heavy_status(state, status, pi_list):
    notify(state, 'i', f"Status parameter: {status}")
    if isinstance(status, bool):
        if status:
            notify(state, 'success', "Finished")
            state.pi_list = pi_list
        else:
            notify(state, 'error', f"An error was raised")
    else:
        state.status += 1
    
def on_action(state):
    invoke_long_callback(state,
                         pi_approx, [int(state.num_iterations)],
                         heavy_status, [],
                         2000)  
        
page = Markdown("""
How many times was the status function called? <|{status}|>

## Number of approximation

<|{num_iterations}|number|label=# of approximation|>

<|Approximate pie|button|on_action=on_action|>

## Evolution of approximation
<|{pi_list}|chart|layout={layout}|>
""")

layout = {
    "yaxis": {
    "type": 'log',
    "autorange": True
    }
  }

Gui(page).run()
```